# Reading pandas column as csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataframe like this one for example:

[image]

```
# Create a dictionary of list
dictionary_of_lists = {
    'id': [29, 25, 33, 24],
    'code': ['30219E103','16951E104','92343E102','90345E103']}
# Create the DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dictionary_of_lists)
```

Then when I extract that df to csv and I opened to output with excel getting this:

[image]

How should I encode when `df.to_csv()` ?

I have tried with "uft-8" and "utf-16" but does not work.

Comment: This isn't a character encoding issue so changing that won't fix anything. This is about how Excel is interpreting your data. The details escape me, but try selecting the column in Excel and changing the cell format to 'text'.

Comment: If you want to read the data with Excel, you can use `df1.to_excel()`.

Comment: Thanks @Ignatius Reilly, it worked extracting as to_excel()